# Is it possible to have a Worker Service running for a DNN website, or do I need to use something else (background service, ajax time interval etc?)

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnetnuke

I have a large query that I want to run every couple of minutes or so in the background of a DNN site. This query (run for MSSQL) takes about 40 seconds to complete, and stores the results in Redis, and the site reads the Redis keys into the UI. I have a Worker Service project that pretty much does this already, but can it work with a DNN site?

Basically, is it possible to have the Worker Service attached to a DNN website, or do I need to use something else, like a background service with an interval, or Ajax call every 2 minutes?  This service should be run regardless of which user is on it (user-agnostic?) and my main concern is not having that 40-second call destroy the UX.

I've tried running the DNN site with the Worker Service as part of the solution, but the Worker Service has to be started (obviously) so it doesn't work when you're browsing the site only (without starting the Service explicitly) and I'm spinning wheels at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with the DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling library. Basically you need to inherit from ScheduleClient which requires you to implement a DoWork() method.

```
public override void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Progressing();
            //DO THE WORK here, make your call to the database
            
            returnMessage += " <br /> Something completed successfully";
            this.ScheduleHistoryItem.Succeeded = true;
            this.ScheduleHistoryItem.AddLogNote(returnMessage);

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            this.ScheduleHistoryItem.Succeeded = false;
            this.ScheduleHistoryItem.AddLogNote("Something Failed, did you configure the settings?");
            this.Errored(ref exc);
        }
    }
```